# Sign up with linkedin not working ( using hybridauth )

Tags: php, social-networking, hybridauth

I am currently using [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) for the integration of social login in a website. The websites url is find.pk. I have added Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Microsoft login in the site and they work perfectly. But the linkedin one just redirects me to the hybridauth root page after taking username and password. Means here: `find.pk/public/social/hybridauth` this is also defined as the base url the config file.

```
ROOT / public / social / hybridauth /   ( The path of the hybridauth lib )
```

and

```
ROOT / pubilc / social / all.php?login={whateverprovider} ( To authenticate using any provided e.g facebook, twitter etc. )
```

You can see the live demo for linkedin login problem:

[find.pk/public/social/all.php?login=linkedin](http://find.pk/public/social/all.php?login=linkedin)

all.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset( $_GET['login'] ))
{
    switch ($_GET['login']) {
        case 'facebook':

        // Now Login with facebook
        $config = "hybridauth/config.php";

        require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Facebook" ); 
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile(); 
        $user_profile = json_decode(json_encode( $user_profile ));
        $_SESSION['social_profile'] = $user_profile;
        header("Location: http://find.pk/user/social_got");
        exit;


        break;

        case 'twitter':

        $config = "hybridauth/config.php";

        require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Twitter" ); 
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile(); 
        $user_profile = json_decode(json_encode( $user_profile ));
        $_SESSION['social_profile'] = $user_profile;
        header("Location: http://find.pk/user/social_got");
        exit;
        break;

        case 'linkedin':

        $config = "hybridauth/config.php";

        require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "LinkedIn" ); 
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
        $user_profile = json_decode(json_encode( $user_profile ));
        $_SESSION['social_profile'] = $user_profile;
        header("Location: http://find.pk/user/social_got");
        exit;

        break;


        case 'google':
        $config = "hybridauth/config.php";

        require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Google" ); 
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
        $user_profile = json_decode(json_encode( $user_profile ));
        $_SESSION['social_profile'] = $user_profile;
        header("Location: http://find.pk/user/social_got");
        exit;

        break;

        case 'live':
        $config = "hybridauth/config.php";

        require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Live" ); 
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
        $user_profile = json_decode(json_encode( $user_profile ));
        $_SESSION['social_profile'] = $user_profile;
        header("Location: http://find.pk/user/social_got");
        exit;

        break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution**

Go to this file: hybridauth/Hybrid/Thirdparty/LinkedIn/LinkedIn.php
(may have different path in your case)

Go to line 126 where `_URL_REQUEST`is defined.

Change this line to this:

```
const _URL_REQUEST                 = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+w_share';
```

**Details:**

The linkedin have made changes to developers programs. so they have changed parameters for requests.

[Details can be read here.](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition)

The main issue is the parameters we are sending with request.

The most prominent is `rw_nus` which is now deprecated. instead use the `w_share`